# AM radio interference with class A amplifier

Tags: amplifier, noise

I am using a class A amplifier constructed around an NPN Darlington transistor (BC517) because the gain I was getting with a single NPN transistor was nowhere close to what I needed. The transistor is biased with two 100K resistor going from collector to base and base to emitter. Instead of a load, I have a 10K resistor, a 100K resistor from the collector drives the input to a comparator (this class A amp is being used as the input stage to a ADC I built). The input comes from an electret mic coupled to the base via a .1uF cap (I have given the mic a proper voltage bias with a 10K resistor). There is some small radio interference with the ADC, which I know how to deal with, but the main problem is that I am getting a massive amount of interference from a nearby AM radio station with my class A amp. The radio waves are being picked up at about the same volume as the sound from the mic. This will not do, so how can I fix it? Should I use a different kind of amplifier (it needs high gain). Is there a way to suppress interference in my existing design?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fSr70I.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Many thanks!

Comment: How much gain? Could we have a circuit diagram? The usual technique for avoiding this problem is to make the entire signal path differential, so common-mode noise gets cancelled out.

Comment: I happen to have open this app note, which is somewhat relevant: http://www.maximintegrated.com/app-notes/index.mvp/id/3573

Comment: Because this phenomena sounds quite odd to me, I'm wondering if it could be any aliasing effect of the ADC. I guess you have a low-pass filter before the ADC, with appropriate cut-off frequency, but please confirm. Additional question, how do yo know the interferences come from AM radio station?

Comment: @RawBean I can hear them talking about football, so I'm sure it's from the AM station XD.

Comment: @pjc50 I will edit my post to include a circuit diagram, and I will read that note and see if it applies to my situation.

Comment: I tried the design in that note. Depending on how I implemented it, I either got silence or still bad radio interference.

Comment: 2 additional questions for me: Do you hear them talking at the output of the ADC? You said you built the ADC. Is there any low-pass filter (for ex. a 22kHz cut-off) before to ensure Nyquist law?

Comment: I think the two BE-diodes, nice and logarithmic at very low bias current, in the Darlington act as a 'perfect' mixer for demodulating AM to baseband.

Comment: I think you need a low pass filter on the input of the amplifier. Anything above 10kHz should be shorted to ground. Your input impedance is pretty hight and therefore an easy target for RF signals to pick up. You need the datasheet of your microphone to check its output impedance and find a preamp circuit that matches that on its input impedance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are picking up AM radio interference because of the relatively high resistances you are using. High resistances make it easier for a low energy signal like a radio wave to imnpress a voltage on a circuit.  I would suggest 2 remedies. One is to reduce all of your resistors by a factor of 10.  Why do you need to put such a large resistor (R4) in series with your output?  Another remedy is to put a small bypass capacitor across R2 to filter out the AM signal.  If you reduce R2 to 10k, then a capacitor of about 200 pf should be sufficient.  If you reduce R2 to 10k, then use a capacitor of about 2000 pf.

Comment: Sorry it took me so long to test this, Thanksgiving break ended and finals started. I am using a slightly different circuit now, but making resistors smaller and adding a capacitor on the base of the transistor did do wonders for smiting that bothersome AM interference. Thanks!